# Formatting date field in Sinatra form

Tags: html, ruby, forms, date, sinatra

I've got a form in Ruby/Sinatra where a date field is displayed:

```
%input{:type => "date", :name => "due_date", :value => @m.due_date}
```

On-screen, the form field presents as `day-month-year` (e.g. 23-11-2012).
I'd like the field content to be displayed as `year-month-day` (e.g. 2012-11-23).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
@m.due_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Take a look at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime

Comment: This yields YYYY-MM-DD in the underlying Ruby but when it is displayed in the above form field, it gets presented as DD-MM-YY.